# Roda script php no cmd com curl

Tags: php, windows, libcurl, cmd

Estou testando uma api, ao tentar utilizar alguns recursos apresentou a seguinte mensagem:

> Something went wrong: Network: CURL error 60: SSL certificate problem:
>   unable to get local issuer certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

Através de pesquisar descobri que era necessário adicionar o certificado cacert.pem no php.ini desta forma:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, porem eu preciso rodar um determinado código da api que só funciona no terminal(cmd) e ao tentar rodar apresenta esta mesma mensagem que aparecia no navegador:

> Something went wrong: Network: CURL error 60: SSL certificate problem:
>   unable to get local issuer certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

Tentei instalar o curl-7.46.0-win64.exe, agora o curl funciona no terminal, mas a mensagem ao tentar rodar a api persiste.

Api: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Estou tentando rodar o exemplo: "pushReceiver.php"

**Update**

Pensei que poderia ser a versão do php já que o wamp tem duas, a 5 e a 7, porem as duas retornam a mesma mensagem:

```
c:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25>php.exe C:\wamp64\www\Instagram\index.php
Something went wrong: Network: CURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

c:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25>cd ..

c:\wamp64\bin\php>cd php7.0.10

c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10>php.exe C:\wamp64\www\Instagram\index.php
Something went wrong: Network: CURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).
```

Comment: de curiosidade, qual a razão de usar o cURL em vez de simplesmente chamar o php.exe index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na pasta do wamp existe mais de um arquivo php.ini, tive que alterar em todas para funcionar, este era o problema.

Pastas onde se encontra os arquivos php.ini:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25
```

Ou seja estava funcionando via browser porque o php.ini do browser esta configurado, mas do console não.